# Breaking minipages over multicols

Tags: minipage, multicol

I'm currently trying to break my two `minipage`'s over two `multicols` columns, but for some reason, my `\break` is pushing my `minipage` to the next page, instead of the next column. Here is my code:

```
\center{
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
\center{
\underline{Untyped Lambda Calculus}
\vspace{11mm}
\begin{align*}
e = \hspace{2mm} & x\\
                 & \lambda x.e\\
                 & e \hspace{2mm} e
\end{align*}
}
\end{minipage}

\break

\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
\center{
\underline{Simply-Typed Lambda Calculus}
\begin{align*}
\tau ::= \tau \rightarrow \tau | T \textrm{\hspace{2mm} where \hspace{2mm}} T \in B
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
e = \hspace{2mm} & x : \tau\\
                 & \lambda (x : \tau).e\\
                 & e \hspace{2mm} e\\
                 & c : T
\end{align*}
}
\end{minipage}
\end{multicols}
}
```

This is near the end of the page. If it was near the middle, then the second `minipage` would be in the right column, as expected. Is there an alternative to `\break` I should be using? Any help with this would be wonderful. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does the problem persist if you replace `\center` with `\centering` -- and omit the outermost `\center` instruction entirely?

Comment: @Mico it does not :\

Comment: `\break` isn't really a latex command, and `multicols` provides `\columnbreak` and as noted your usage of `\center` is incorrect, although doesn't affect the column breaking.

Comment: why don't you just put two minipage side by side, you don't seem to be using `multicols` at all here.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Your answer was correct! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\break` isn't really a latex command, and `multicols` provides `\columnbreak` and as noted in comments, your usage of `\center` is incorrect, although doesn't affect the column breaking.